# Internet Explorer CSS width: calc()

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/dm7pxv1k/1/

I've got a problem with IE, when i've got 3 divs with background-image in 1 row and everyone has `width: calc(100% / 3);`.

If you resize a window, third image blinks.

When you resize the window to big resolution like `.banner-mini` has at least `width:2000px;`, then third image dissapears totally.

I've also implemented browser prefixes - you can see in Fiddle.

Has anybody please any idea, how I could fix that? Thank you so much!

Btw: Other browsers are allright.

Comment: See the computed value that IE is setting. For sure the total width of the three elements is more than 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little and easy workaround for this is to reduce the width by 1px:

```css
.banner-mini{
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.banner-mini .box{
  float: left;
  width: 33%; /** older browsers **/ 
  width: -webkit-calc((100% / 3) - 1px); /** Safari 6, Chrome 19-25 **/
  width: -moz-calc((100% / 3) - 1px); /** FF 4-15  **/
  width:  calc((100% / 3) - 1px); /** FF 16+, IE 9+, Opera 15, Chrome 26+, Safari 7 and future other browsers **/
  height: 100%;
}
.banner-mini .fst{
  background: url(http://s33.postimg.org/q43iabwtr/banner_1.jpg)  no-repeat center center; 
  background-size: 100%;
}
.banner-mini .snd{
  background: url(http://s33.postimg.org/tozdtk1db/banner_2.jpg)  no-repeat center center; 
  background-size: 100%;
}
.banner-mini .trd{
  background: url(http://s33.postimg.org/lkr9otey7/banner_3.jpg)  no-repeat center center; 
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-mini">
  <div class="box fst"></div>
  <div class="box snd"></div>
  <div class="box trd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1px is noticeable (it is 3 pixels in total for 3 elements), to fix IE rounding it is enough to subtract 0.01px which doesn't cause any visible rendering artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

IE has not very precise rounding (you can find more info about this [here](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/)), you should subtract some unnoticeably small value from result to fix this:

```
width: calc(100% / 3 - 0.01px);
```

Live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/L9duvu9q/1/

Answer (score 1):

IE is still a bit messy on rounding value.

Consider a `calc(99.9% / 3)` to solve your problem.